# WSL nginx error.log and access.log are filling up all my disk space periodicly

Tags: nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After some time depending on what I am working on the file size of error.log and access.log of nginx is getting to big. I have to manually delete the file content so I can work normally for some time.
Is there a way I can periodically delete these?

Comment: You can try with `logrotate` - https://serverfault.com/questions/427144/how-to-limit-nginx-access-log-file-size-and-compress or https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,13669